# How to incrementally migrate CRA flow to typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, create-react-app, flowtype

There is a create-react-app project setup with flow.
We want to migrate it to typescript.

Following instructions here
https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-typescript
I added typescript.

Now I get compile errors that types can only be used in `.ts` files.

If I change js files to ts typescript being stricter than flow starts complaining with a lot of errors. So I have to rewrite the whole app at once.

What are the ways to workaround this and migrate to ts incrementally?

Comment: You can switch off type checking temporally with transpileOnly: true option.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by using `include` and `exclude` properties of tsconfig.

```js
{
  "include": [
    "src/components",
  ]
}
```